# Meteor's Session.set causing issues with JQuery code?

Tags: jquery, meteor

I am using Meteor 0.5.4 I have just encountered a strange issue with Meteor's Session.set().

I want to show a simple modal dialogue when user clicks on a template instance.

I am using Template's event map to set some info into Session when user clicks onto a Template instance.

```
Template.Orders.events({
'click' : function () {
    Session.set("OrderName", this.name);
}
});
```

Modal dialogue template then displays the data set in Session:

```
Template.OrderDialogue.OrderName = function() {
    return Session.get("OrderName");
}
```

and finally here's my JQuery code

```
Template.Orders.rendered = function() {
    jQuery('a[rel*=leanModal]').leanModal();
}
```

When I use Session.set() - as showed above inside Template.orders's click event handler - JQuery plugin doesn't show the modal dialogue on the first click on the template instance but only on second click on that exact instance. It takes two clicks on template instance to get the modal dialogue.

When I remove Session.set() everything is working fine - modal dialogue is shown on first click as it's supposed to work.

Debug output shows that Session value is properly set on the first click.

How can Session.set() interfere with my JQuery plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`leanModal` is showing the HTML content of `OrderDialogue` before the Meteor engine reactively infuses the new content into it, so the key is to wrap the `leanModal` click in a `setTimeout` to ensure the reactivity has happened.

Assuming you have:

```
<template name="OrderDialogue">
    <div id="overlay_content">
       <h1>{{OrderName}}</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<template name="Orders">
    {{#each order}}
        <a href="#overlay_content" rel="leanModal">{{name}}</a>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

And your javascript:

```
Template.Orders.events({
   'click' : function () {
      Session.set("OrderName", this.name);
   }
});

Template.OrderDialogue.OrderName = function() {
   return Session.get("OrderName");
}

Template.Orders.rendered = function() {
   $("a[rel*=leanModal]").leanModal();
}
```

Then you have to hack the leanmodal widget with a `setTimeout` on the click event handler, to give the reactivity a moment to render the `OrderName` content prior to event bubbling.

Assuming [this is the script](https://raw.github.com/FinelySliced/leanModal.js/master/jquery.leanModal.js), wrap the click handler in this script (starting around line 23) like this:

```
$(this).click(function(e) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var modal_id = $(this).attr("href");
        ...
    }, 1);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction TimDog. For some reason modifying the JQuery plugin didn't worked for me - no dialogue was shown after adding setTimeout. Having info from you I inserted Meteor.flush() after Session.set() in Order template's event handlers and that did it. Now I get the modal dialogue shown on a first click. Thanks, Vladimir