# Meteor session.set/get and jquery modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

After swipe event, session is set with the _id of this. Then, I pass this._id to the helper that shows a button inside the #each item. After click on this button, modal will be open and I can delete the item. 
The HTML code:

```
<template name="territories">
 <ul class="collection">
    {{#each territories}}
         {{> item}}
    {{/each}}
 </ul>
</template>

<template name="item">
 <li class="collection-item hammerDiv">
        {{#if deletable}}
            <a href="#delmodal" class="waves-effect modal-trigger-item btn flat">Cancella</a>
        {{/if}}
        <div>{{name}} - n.{{number}}<a href="{{pathFor 'owners'}}" class="secondary-content">{{owners.length}}</a></div>
  </li>
  <div id="delmodal" class="modal">
        <p>Sei sicuro di cancellare il territorio? Perderai tutte le note.</p>
        <div class="row">
            <a href="#" id="dismiss-cancel" class="waves-effect btn flat modal_close">Annulla</a>
            <a href="#" id="delTerr" class="waves-effect btn flat modal_close">Cancella</a>
        </div>
  </div>
```

The JS code:

```
Template.territories.helpers({
    territories : function(){
        return Territories.find();
    }
});

Template.item.helpers({
    deletable : function(){
        var thisTerr = Session.get('deletable-item');
        if (this._id == thisTerr){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }
});

Template.item.events({
'swipeleft .hammerDiv': function(e, t) {
        e.preventDefault();
        Session.set('deletable-item', this._id);
    }
});

Template.item.rendered = function(){
    //modal
    $('.modal-trigger-item').leanModal();

    //swipe gesture on the item, works fine
    $('li.hammerDiv').hammer({
        drag_min_distance:1,
        swipe_velocity:0.1
    });
};
```

Modal works only when I remove {{#if deletable}} in the HTML: in this case the button is always visible and modal works fine. But I would like the button to appear inside the item when Session is set to this._id, and then, on click to this one, show the modal. 
I think problem is reactivity of DOM with Session.set. 
I tried to apply [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14427422/meteors-session-set-causing-issues-with-jquery-code) and [this](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Blaze_Notes) suggestions without results.
Your help is appreciated. ;-)

Comment: Try to console.log both id's in helper and check if they are same

Comment: Yep, button show/hide works fine. Problem is to show modal when I click the button. Modal appears only when I don't use session.set/get

Comment: You mean your 'deletable' helper doesn't work well? That's what I assumed when writing this comment. Try to console log this._id and Session.get to compare fields and maybe this will get you closer to the answer

Comment: Helper works fine because button is show only Within the swiped item. The problem is when I click in the button and modal don't appear. Sorry for the bad english but I'm italian :-)

Comment: You don't have any event to support the click of this <a> tag, are you trying to trigger it by those events in rendered function? Rendered only works when those items you are trying to assign are visible in the moment of rendering. Because of {{#if}} in html those elements aren't visible then

Comment: Ok @sindis how can I render the jquery to open modal in the single button item?

Comment: 'click  .modal-trigger-item' :function(e){
   $(e.currentTarget).leanModal();
} - this may not be the best idea, cause you would probably had to click them twice

Comment: Or you can simply wrap it up in divs that have display: none, rendered will see them then even tho they are hidden, and then just change display in helper

Comment: So are you suggesting me to eliminate the template.render and use only the click event @sindis?

Comment: As I said, click event won't probably be good idea because leanModal() jsut create event so you would have to click it twice, the easiest way to do it is to wrap every .modal-trigger-item into div which has display as 'none' and then change it in js after click. Just like you did, but not with sessions, with styles

Comment: Hi @Arcy, is it a jQueryUI Modal or a Bootstrap Modal you are trying to show?

Comment: Hi @physiocoder, the entire framework is Materialize, a porting from Google Material Design. Modal used is leanModal

Comment: Ok, so the problem could be that your `$('.modal-trigger').leanModal();` code is executed when the `.modal-trigger`element is not in the DOM, and when it is inserted in the DOM no one initialize it. Otherwise if the `.modal-trigger` is in the DOM from the beginning (because you removed `{{#if deletable}}`) the plugin gets correctly initialized (in `.rendered()` method I suppose). Could be an explanation? (something similar to what @Sindis was saying...)

Comment: Thanks @physiocoder, the theory about this question now is ok. I tried the suggestions posted in my answer, the links on the bottom page, but don't works. Can you suggest me how render correctly using my example code? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dirty trick I've used a couple of times is this:

```
Template.item.helpers({
    deletable : function(){
        var thisTerr = Session.get('deletable-item');
        if (this._id == thisTerr){
            setTimeout(function() { $('.modal-trigger').leanModal(); }, 0);
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }
});
```

So that the code that initialize the plugin is executed immediately after DOM update by Blaze (when the `<a>`element is already rendered).